# How can I get XPATH to return a node between two different siblings?

Tags: xpath, pom.xml, siblings

I am working on pom file modifications to change the version node value.  I can get xpath to modify all version nodes, but I only want it to change the version node when both the artifactId and classifier match certain values.  Here is my xml:

```
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>config</classifier>
    <type>zip</type>
    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
</artifactItem>
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</artifactItem>
```

If artifactId is foobar, and classifier is config, I want version returned so I can modify it.

Using other examples I found, I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
/artifactItem/artifactId[.='foobar']
     /following-sibling::*
      [count(.|/artifactItem/classifier[. ='config']/preceding-sibling::*)
      =
      count(/artifactItem/classifier[. ='config']/preceding-sibling::*)
      ]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//artifactItem[artifactId='foobar' and classifier='config']/version
```

To explain:

We are selecting the version node, from the artifactItem node that has an artifactId of 'foobar' AND a classifier of 'config'.

You use the brackets to qualify a particular node using sub-XPATH statements where the context is the node before the brackets.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: that probably will do it, but I think we have a bug in our perl module processing my xpath.  I will update when we clean that up.

Comment: This worked, thanks.  We had to switch the perl module we were using from Twig.pm to XPath.pm.  We couldn't get Twig to handle the 'and' operator.  Thanks again for the help!